# Adldap2 : Uncaught Error: Class 'Adldap\Adldap' not found

Tags: class, ldap, composer-php

I'm trying to install Adldap2 (not the Laravel version) with composer but I get an error message.

- https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2
- https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2/#/installation

**Composer version :**

2.2.18

**I think that there is no installation error** :
[image]

**Error :**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Adldap\Adldap' not found in /var/www/html/test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/test.php on line 17

**Code :**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$config = [
    'hosts'            => ['xxx.local'],
    'base_dn'          => 'dc=xxx,dc=localg',
    'username'         => 'xxx',
    'password'         => 'xxx',

    'custom_options'   => [
        LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT => LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_HARD
    ]
];

$ad = new Adldap\Adldap();
?>
```

Anyone know why I get this error ?

Comment: The documentation uses `$ad = new \Adldap\Adldap();`, with an additional backslash in the beginning. Did you try to use that?

Comment: Same error.
It's written like this in the documentation `$ad = new Adldap\Adldap();`

https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2/#/setup

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? Does the `vendor` folder contain the given class?

Comment: No.., so I search for it `find /type d -name "*ldap*"` and I noticed that the package is installed on `root/vendor/adldap2` instead of `var/www/html/vendor/adldap2`, I don't understand why it's installing in this folder.

Comment: Why not check the output of `composer install` once more? The screenshot you've shared (which contains solely text, so sharing it as such is way better!) contains an obvious hint: don't run Composer using `sudo`

Comment: I think the issue was because I was in root folder in my terminal when I launched the commands. I move to /var/www/html/ and launch back `composer require adldap2/adldap2` and I get a new error `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires adldap/adldap ^10.4.2, found adldap/adldap[dev-master, 5.0.0.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
`

Comment: I run `composer remove adldap/adldap` and run back 'composer require adldap2/adldap2` and it install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked in the `/var/www/html/vendor/` folder and noticed that my package `adldap2/adldap2` was not in (thanks @Nico Hasse). So I searched for a "ldap" folder in all my files and noticed that it was installed in `/vendor/` folder

I was in my root folder instead of my project folder `/var/www/html/`
I moved to my project folder and launch back the package installation and it worked.